# dynamic_reconfigure

Tags: dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to:

```
rosrun dynamic_reconfigure reconfigure_gui
```

in following the instructions here to configure my kinect:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera

however, the gui window that comes up is blank?! (no controls or fields, unlike what is shown in the example on the link above).  Any idea what could be going on?  I'm able to run rviz and have qt4 installed.  I'm running on diamondback with ubuntu 11.04.

Thanks,
Walt

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11517/dynamic_reconfigure/) by [walt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1195/walt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2011-10-12

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try launching the openni node first, then run this command then you should be able to see the options.

---

Originally posted by [evolutionsdisaster](https://answers.ros.org/users/1196/evolutionsdisaster/) with karma: 71 on 2011-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-10-18**:
It sounds like you have an independent problem with your Kinect.  I suggest that you ask that with more details in a seperate question after looking for similar problems from other users.

**Comment by [walt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1195/walt/) on 2011-10-12**:
walt@T5500:~/ros_workspace$ roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch  the kinect is identified, serial number listed, and rgb and depth frame id's exist.  However, the red laser on the kinect doesn't come on! No data is published from the camera.  I've had the kinect sending data recently...

**Comment by [walt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1195/walt/) on 2011-10-12**:
It looks like there is a problem with the openni_node working correctly.    When I do this: